# How to turn SPA React app into SSR with Flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, server-side-rendering

I have an existing React app that makes ajax calls to a Flask API to fetch the data it needs. This approach worked until I learned my pages must be rendered server-side for social media cards to display properly. I need some help migrating the SPA React app to SSR with Flask

Flask app file structure:

```
flaskapp
- models.py
- templates/
- api/
  - routes.py
run.py
```

React app file structure:

```
src
- views/
- app.tsx
- routes.tsx
```

Currently, all the routing and authentication (Firebase) is done client-side so I will need to take this into consideration as well.

What are the steps of moving this to SSR and are there any good resources/tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: checkout `renderToString` with `react-dom/server` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Comment: The solution is Next.js for those wondering. https://nextjs.org/